# Interpret the HLSL Shader Compiler Macro code

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl

Profile:
WiN7 Prof SP1

Directx11

Development IDE: VS 2015

Program Language:  C#

Application Type:  3D Rendering

Directx11 Wrapper: SLimDX

In my C# project I have a 3D renderer that is working.

I want to integrate a third Party HLSL Shader Code.

I have translated the code for Directx11 Feature level and it compiles with fxc.exe without errors or warnings.

The shader is loaded by my C# application and I can access all shader variables and set values of them.

Problem:

When I try to get a reference in my C# Code to access the first pass of the first technique of the Shader I get a SlimDX runtime Error.

I can reference the first technique of the shader with no runtime error but the obtained object has a flag is_valid = false showing the technique was not referenced correctly.

Clarification: I don't try to make a draw call but in preparation of the draw call I have to get a reference to the relevant pass.

Question:

I can't understand what the last compiler directives about the techniques mean exactly.

Can someone translate which HLSL Code will eventually produced from the compiler directive?

I mean the beginning from :

#define OBJECT_TEC(name, mmdpass) \

```
#include "../ray.conf"
#include "../ray_advanced.conf"
#include "../shader/math.fxsub"
#include "../shader/common.fxsub"
#include "../shader/gbuffer.fxsub"
#include "../shader/lighting.fxsub"

float3  LightDirection  : DIRECTION < string Object = "Light"; >;
float3  LightSpecular   : SPECULAR  < string Object = "Light"; >;

bool ExistRay : CONTROLOBJECT<string name = "ray.x";>;

texture DiffuseMap: MATERIALTEXTURE;
sampler DiffuseMapSamp = sampler_state
{
    texture = <DiffuseMap>;
    MINFILTER = ANISOTROPIC;
    MAGFILTER = ANISOTROPIC;
    MIPFILTER = POINT;
    MAXANISOTROPY = 16;
    ADDRESSU  = WRAP;
    ADDRESSV  = WRAP;
};

float4 GetTextureColor(float4 albedo, float2 uv)
{
    if (use_texture)
    {
        float4 TexColor = tex2D(DiffuseMapSamp, uv);
        TexColor.rgb = lerp(1, TexColor * TextureMulValue + TextureAddValue, TextureMulValue.a + TextureAddValue.a).rgb;
        albedo *= TexColor;
    }

    return srgb2linear(albedo);
}

void DrawObjectVS(
    in float4 Position : POSITION,
    in float3 Normal   : NORMAL,
    in float4 Texcoord : TEXCOORD0,
    out float4 oTexcoord  : TEXCOORD0,
    out float3 oNormal    : TEXCOORD1,
    out float3 oViewdir   : TEXCOORD2,
    out float4 oPosition  : SV_Position)
{
    oNormal = Normal;
    oTexcoord = Texcoord;
    oViewdir = CameraPosition - Position.xyz;
    oPosition = mul(Position, matWorldViewProject);
}

float4 DrawObjectPS(float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0, float3 normal : TEXCOORD1, float3 viewdir : TEXCOORD2) : SV_Target
{
#if EXIST_RAY
    #if DISCARD_ALPHA_ENABLE
        float alpha = MaterialDiffuse.a;
    #if DISCARD_ALPHA_MAP_ENABLE
        if (use_texture) alpha *= tex2D(DiffuseMapSamp, texcoord.xy).a;
    #endif
        clip(alpha - DiscardAlphaThreshold);
    #endif
        return 0;
#else
    if (ExistRay)
    {
#if DISCARD_ALPHA_ENABLE
        float alpha = MaterialDiffuse.a;
#if DISCARD_ALPHA_MAP_ENABLE
        if (use_texture) alpha *= tex2D(DiffuseMapSamp, texcoord.xy).a;
#endif
        clip(alpha - DiscardAlphaThreshold);
#endif
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        float4 albedo = GetTextureColor(MaterialDiffuse, texcoord.xy);

        float3 L = normalize(-LightDirection);
        float3 V = normalize(viewdir);
        float3 N = normalize(normal);

        float MaterialRoughness = SmoothnessToRoughness(ShininessToSmoothness(MaterialPower));

        float4 lighting = albedo;
        lighting.rgb *= DiffuseBRDF(N, L, V, MaterialRoughness);
        lighting.rgb += SpecularBRDF_GGX(N, L, V, MaterialRoughness, 0.04, 1.0);
        lighting.rgb *= LightSpecular;

        return linear2srgb(lighting);
    }
#endif
}

#define OBJECT_TEC(name, mmdpass) \
    technique name < string MMDPass = mmdpass;\
    > { \
        pass DrawObject { \
            AlphaTestEnable = FALSE; AlphaBlendEnable = FALSE; \
            VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 DrawObjectVS(); \
            PixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 DrawObjectPS(); \
        } \
    }

OBJECT_TEC(MainTec0, "object")
OBJECT_TEC(MainTecBS0, "object_ss")

technique EdgeTec < string MMDPass = "edge"; > {}
technique ShadowTech < string MMDPass = "shadow";  > {}
technique ZplotTec < string MMDPass = "zplot"; > {}
```